# Problem to identify when a WebView Downloads a file

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, webview

I have been faced a problem in React Native (environment android) to identify when a WebView downloads a file.

The current version of WebView is "react-native-webview": "^11.15.0"

The WebView component charges an url, this url redirects to some web sites and finally downloads a pdf file.

```
<WebView
   onNavigationStateChange={handleWebViewNavigationStateChange}
   source={{uri: my_url_link}}
   style={styles.webviewStyles}
/>
```

And I have a function that triggers when the url link changes, so my question is how can i handle the download event

```
const handleWebViewNavigationStateChange = (newNavState: any) => {
  // url from the webview state
  const {url} = newNavState;

  // Handler PDFView
  if (url.includes('.pdf')) {
    console.log('Its a PDF');
  }
};
```

I have been tried with [onFileDownload WebView method](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onFileDownload) but only works for IOS platforms. So i want to tried with some native solution, any idea of how can I could handle the download event?